# Angularjs Error in loading external jsonfile from server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to load json file from  server .Here is my services.js file

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

/**
 * A simple example service that returns some data.
 */
.factory('Friends', function($http) {

  var friends;
 //here is the code for server access
  $http.get('http://wwww.root5solutions.com/ionictest/get.json').then(function(msg){
      console.log("console output"+msg.data);
      friends=msg.data;
      console.log("from server"+friends.data);
  });

  return {
    all: function() {
      return friends;
    },
    get: function(friendId) {

      return friends[friendId];
    }
  }
});
```

But its not worked properly.Here is my console message

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.root5solutions.com/ionictest/get.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: The server does not support CORS, see http://enable-cors.org/server.html on how to enable it.

Comment: Can you show example codes for me

Comment: I just added the following code to my js file,but didnt work
`$http.defaults.headers.put = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  };`

Comment: It's the server that decides if it wants to provide CORS support or not. There's nothing you can do in javascript to enable it.

Comment: I tried in localhost ,but didnt work.Is it possible that in localhost

Comment: Works perfectly in device,but didnt work in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have also faced the same problem.I am sure it will resolve your problem,**

> For Windows... create a Chrome shortcut on your desktop > Right-clic > properties > Shortcut > Edit "target" path : > "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security

**NOTE:** **After setting this exit from chrome and then open**

---

Comment: http get working fine.But http post reutrns this error `Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. `

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr and also check this http://www.wilsolutions.com.br/content/fix-request-header-field-content-type-not-allowed-access-control-allow-headers

Comment: Finally i figure out the problem,but never get a solution.Http get working fine ,post returns the same error.

Comment: Either my answer helped you or not?

Comment: Can you give an answer for this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831459/pushnotifcation-in-phongap-android-multiple-registrion-ids-of-the-same-device)

Comment: Then can you please mark my answer as correct for your above question? So that the others can also make use this answer....

Answer (score 0):

you have to whitelist that URL

try this

```
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {

    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        // Allow same origin resource loads.
        'self',
        // Allow loading from our other assets domain.  Note there is a difference between * and **.
        'http://wwww.root5solutions.com/ionictest/**',
    ]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All this problem beacuse i tested only using browser.When tesing on device/emulator its working perfect.There is no need of additional coding to overcome this problem.