# Angular js http request php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send form data on angular js to php page. bu it's not working. 
here's my form:

and this is my $http request

```
    nodes.controller("addNew",function($http){
    var  content = this;

    this.submitNew = function(type)
    {
        //content.body.filter
       $http({method:'POST',url:http+'nodes/create',

               data:{
                   title:content.title,
                   author:content.author,
                   node_author:content.node_author,
                   body:content.body,
                   type:type
               },
               headers:{
                   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"POST",
                   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
               }
           }

       );
        this.title = '';
        this.author = '';
        this.body = '';

    }
});
```

this error!!!

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hangoma.lc/nodes/create. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

header details

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://hangoma.lc/nodes/create
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

Please help!!! i cannot find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to make request to `http://hangoma.lc/nodes/create` from `127.0.0.1`. But the remote server does not allows connection from other servers (except `http://hangoma.lc`).

The server you are trying to connect should include the `access-control-` headers. You can not force these from your request.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr) question has more details.