# IONIC, Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to send http request with $http (angular) with this code:

```
$http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'http://192.168.0.17:9000',
              header: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"},
        }).then(getEventsSuccess, getEventsError);
```

But this doesn't work and I have in the web console this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.17:9000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin must be set Server-Side, not client side

Comment: sounds like CORS issue

Comment: I do it on both side but same problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr)

Comment: @TarikMerabet check headers

Comment: I have add the headers for my server but it's doesn't change anything.

Comment: The message "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" is self-explaining. Could you check on your browser's debugging tool the Response headers if they are correctly set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see this error due to a security mechanism implemented in your browser, called Same Origin Policy.

Basically, it is caused since your webpage tries to access a resource which resides on a server that is on a different Host, Port or Scheme (HTTP / HTTPS / file etc) than the webpage itself.

In order to solve this issue, you can do one of the following:

- Serve your Webpage from the server that you are trying to access. If your webpage URL will be http://192.168.0.17:9000/X.html, your request should be successful and the error will disappear.
- Add a special header to the response sent from your server, called Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Read more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS