# Url to cordova app - Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid

I'm facing a issue in a cordova (ionic) app that I'm currently developing. 
I need to go to a webpage in the cordova window which then will have a pointer back to the app url it self containing some extra url params which i need to consume. All is well except that when i try to show the app again i get

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/index.html?token=eyJzdGF0d
```

guessing this is due to some security policy.

Anyone know how to get around this? using in-app-browser is not really an option.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951753/ionic-access-control-allow-origin