# Cannot set headers

Tags: node.js, express, cors

This probably may be a duplicate question, but I'm not able to do this correctly.

I have enabled CORS in my backend (reading [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)). But, still, when I try to hit an API on my API server through my UI server, I get this:

`Request header field Authentication is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Here are some relevant parts of my code:

#### Backend

```
// enable CORS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

#### Frontend

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: ...,
    headers: {
        Authentication: ...
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Put `Authentication` in your `res.header`   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to use [express cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) module like

```
var cors = require('cors');


// enable CORS
app.use(cors());
```

and do not forgot to install

```
npm install cors --save
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow that header explicitly

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authentication");
```

And you'd better use some existing CORS module, as I'm not sure your implementation is 100% correct.

I use this CORS middleware:

```
function (req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", YOUR_URL); // restrict it to the required domain
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    // Set custom headers for CORS
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", YOUR_HEADER_STRING);

    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        return res.status(200).end();
    }

    return next();
};
```

Comment: Can you suggest me what I could have improved? I think the only thing I'm doing wrong right now is by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as `*`

Comment: @AnubhavDhawan take a look at this cors module for example: https://github.com/expressjs/cors. I will add the code that I use that takes pre-flight requests into account