# I am using react and axios. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: reactjs, post, redux, axios

axios. post error.

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I am using the `axios`, `react` and `redux`.

My code is:

```
  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: addActivityUrl,
    data:data,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.request(config)
        .then(function(response){
          dispatch({type:ADD_ACTIVITY_SUCCESS,payload:response.data});
        } )
        .catch((error)=> {
          dispatch({type:ADD_ACTIVITY_ERROR,payload:error});
        })
  }
}
```

I set the breakpoint in the error callback function. When I send a post request,the error above will show me.

I looked for the answer on Stack Overflow. I don't found the answer yet.

I don't know the reason.

Comment: Give this a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: You have to add your access-control setting on your server-side. Think about it.. Wouldnt it be quite a security concern if a client could define your server side configurations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr)

Answer (score 2):

Most you have an issue with custom request headers.

When using custom request header you will get a CORS preflight. This type of request use HTTP OPTIONS and includes Access-Control-Request-Headers listing the headers the client wants to include in the request.

Your client code need to reply to CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS headers. That header needs to contain the same values the Access-Control-Request-Headers.

Comment: I delete  ` headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },.    `                                                                      The post is OK.

Comment: @jiexishede in this case make sure js and api are on the same domain. Same Domain Policy security

Comment: I don't understand it now. I will learn more and more to understand your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jiexishede if you found my answer useful, please do not forget to upvote it :) thanks

Comment: @GibboK, I am having the same issue, which dependencies can solve this error? And I am having a API having "/file.json" in the end. And I am trying to access it using react, I am not getting the list, but if I try by postman and other calls it works. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the CORS error in console. I'm Using PHP in backend.
What i did is just remove this:

```
headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
```

So it look's like this:-

```
await axios({
            method:'post',
            url:'http://127.0.0.1/PHP_API_POSTMAN/react_to_do_api/insert.php',
            data:formData          
        })
```

Data is successfully hitting the PHP end point.