# Jquery ajax not able to load the script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url,
    dataType: dataType,
    crossDomain: false
}).done(function(data) {
    callback(null, data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (jqXHR.statusText === 'OK') {
        console.log('Unable to load resource:', url, 'error:', errorThrown);
    }
    callback(errorThrown)
});
```

For the above ajax request call i am facing some errors

**Error 1:**
Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight

**Error 2:** 
DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load

Comment: so is the client making the call to the server? in a quick google search for the first error pulled up this stack overflow question which might relatate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr

Answer (score 0):

The server you're trying to hit is preventing the browser from completing the request via its HTTP access control policy ([CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)). Specifically the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers".

You need to either:

- Configure the server to allow "X-Requested-With" header, or:
- Remove the "X-Requested-With" from jQuery's AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid synchronous requests. They are deprecated. Read this article on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).
2. You are facing the **same-origin policy** implemented by all web browsers. Since **CORS** is apparently not available for you, you should rely on [JSONP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/).
3. If you want to load a script, it would be better to use [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Comment: Thanks for your respose but i have tried with getScript but on success callback response i am getting undefined data even if the data is present.

Comment: "undefined data even if the data is present". What do you mean? What do you see in your dev tools? Do you have any warning or error message?

Comment: it's very strange there is no error in console just giving undefined inside  success callback

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause when we make an ajax call to the js file with dataType = 'script'

when we mention dataType = 'script' it will evals the script data and returns the data inside the success callback.
suppose if the js file is having any error during eval(js) it will find the error and it will returns undefined inside the success callback.