# How to send both data and header to a server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to send a header to a server using http call POST request.
When I send the header only, everything is ok.
but when I add some data to the call, I get an error:

```
http://localhost:3000/test_post. 
Request header field Content-Type is not
allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I use node.js as the server side language, this is the code for the CORS settings:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-auth"); 
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-auth"); 

next();
});
```

This is the `$http` call with angular:

```
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    data: {name: 'Dani'},
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/test_post'
    headers: {
        'x-auth': 'some token'
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

    console.log(response.data);

}, function errorCallback(response) {

    console.log('error');
});
```

I know problem is about the CORS, but I don't know what to modify there,
If I remove `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-auth");` from the CORS I can get the data on the server but not the Header.

How can I get them both?
Hope you can help me with that, Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr)

Comment: Please search for possible answers before asking. This question has been solved dozens of times.

Comment: @lin it's not the same question, I did put the cors on my server

Comment: Please read the answers carefully. The linked question does solve your problem since the error is the same.