# API call getting CORS error in ReactJS but getting response in node and postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, cors, cross-domain

I am trying to call APIs to the popular servers like OwnCloud, Openfire, and Ejabberd which are installed in my local server. I am creating a ReactJS website. Initially, I used the **`fetch()`** method to access the API. But I am getting the CORS error as the result.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://x.x.x.x:8088/api/contacts/3000@x.x.x.x' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I checked the same APIs using Postman and successfully got the response. Then I tested it with the node code below using the command line and got the API response in the command line.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "x.x.x.x",
  "port": "8088",
  "path": "/api/contacts/3000@x.x.x.x",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "e5a6f2bb-abc9-8ce7-f237-342ab53ab9d6"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

I implemented the same node code into my ReactJS code and getting the same CORS error again.

I've added the below headers to the **`fetch()`** method's header and getting the same CORS error.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, content-type, accept, authorization',
```

I added **`mode: "cors"`** into the **`fetch()`** method. But still same error.

Could you please provide a solution to avoid this **`*CORS*`** issue?

Comment: Maybe this solution works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a local proxy for API calls.

Here, proxy uses url pattern to match to the api calls and redirecting them to the corresponding server.

Try with the following:

- Install http-proxy-middleware

  ```
  npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
  ```
- create src/setupProxy.js

  ```
  const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

  module.exports = function(app) {

     app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:8088/' }));

  };
  ```
- Then run your local Dev server

Comment: Does this code integrate with ReactJS code? If not, the server not having the feature of editing the code.

Comment: The above code creates a local proxy to forward API calls from one port(localhost:3030) to another port(localhost:8088).