# How to axios POST select form values on change with a select dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, material-ui

I have a select form from MaterialUI that is populated with choices that I received via an axios `GET` request. This works, however, **I now need to axios `POST` request the selected option in my `handleChange(event)` function. The data I need to `POST` from the select drop down should be the `string` value of the `MenuItem`, not an index or key.**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 250,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    firm: '',
    infosys: '',
    spot: '',
  });
  const [choices, setChoices] = React.useState([])

  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(100)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/form/',
      );
      console.log('RESULT DATA: ', result.data)
      setChoices(result.data)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(values);
}, [values]);
```

**Below is the area where the issue likely is:**

```
  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues({
      firm: event.target.value
    })
  }

  const selectOptions = choices.map((choice, index) =>
    <MenuItem key={index} value={choice} primarytext={choice}>{choice} 
    </MenuItem>
  ) 

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">

      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="firm-helper">Firm</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={values.firm}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input name="firm" id="firm-helper" />}
        >
          {selectOptions}  
        </Select>
        <FormHelperText>Select a Firm</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    <form>
  )
```

**I expect to be able to axios `POST` request in my `handleChange` function whenever the selected option in the drop down menu changes. I wish to `POST` the `firm` value in my `values` dictionary**

**Current Output:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/form/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
xhr.js:166 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/form/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point you're using `console.log`, `values` will still be the old (current) value. You'll need to use `useEffect` to execute some kind of effect based on `values` changing. If you remove your current console logging and add this, you should see a better result. Note: passing the array with `values` in as the second argument is what tells this effect to happen whenever `values` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(values);
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.post(url, { values: values });
  };
  fetchData(); 
}, [values]);
```

Comment: thank  you this makes sense I will update., however, I am still stuck with how to axios POST the selected value.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you might do a post request using axios from within `useEffect`!

Comment: Thank you! this works! However, I am now getting a different error even though the post is being made. I have updated with the new output.

Comment: Well now you'll have to google `CORS`! Basically, you have to configure your back-end to accept requests from your front-end.

Comment: haha I am very close! I do have it setup in the backend, but am unsure if the issue is actually there or in the front end.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read your error close enough: `Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr