# Using Rails, how should I configure my application.rb in order to allow for CORS requests to take place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, post, axios, cors

I am using Rails as a backend API to support a frontend that is made with VueJS. I want to send a POST request from VueJS when a button is pressed on the website, I have used axios to do this
`

```
methods: {
    // Performs a POST request to the rails endpoint and passes the email and pass as parameters
        signup() {
          if (this.password === this.password_confirmation) {
            this.$http.plain
              .post("/signup", {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation
              })
              // If successful execute signinSuccesful
              .then(response => this.signinSuccesful(response))
              // If it doesn't run for whatever reason, execute signupFailed
              .catch(error => this.signinFailed(error));
          }
      },`
```

This should in theory create a POST request that would be received by the API, I have attempted to catch the request like this: `post "signup", controller: :signup, action: :create`

However, when I look in the console on chrome I get an error when I first load the site:

```
`0/signin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
```

And another error when I click the button to send the POST request:
*

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/signup' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
>   header field content-type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

My 'application.rb' file looks like this:

```
`module RecordstoreBackend
     class Application < Rails::Application
        # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
        config.load_defaults 6.0
        config.api_only = true

        config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
          allow do
            origins '*'
            resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :patch, :put, :delete, :post, :options]
          end
        end`
```

I think the issue is this file, but I am not sure how to configure it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like you're missing the host for that request (on your Vue app). Notice the error says `0/signup` which indicates that it's sending the request to `http://0/signup` that is, in turn, "rejecting" the connection.

I'm not familiar with Vue.js structure, but I'd recommend encapsulating the axios call on a plugin that would use the `host` from an environment configuration file, so that you can have different hosts for localhost and your production env. Or even just add the host to your environment:

```js
methods: {
    // Performs a POST request to the rails endpoint and passes the email and pass as parameters
        signup() {
          if (this.password === this.password_confirmation) {
            this.$http.plain
              .post(`${process.env.API_HOST}/signup`, {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation
              })
              // If successful execute signinSuccesful
              .then(response => this.signinSuccesful(response))
              // If it doesn't run for whatever reason, execute signupFailed
              .catch(error => this.signinFailed(error));
          }
      },
```

Reference: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

If you want to fix it the way you have it now, simply add your host to the axios call:

```js
methods: {
    // Performs a POST request to the rails endpoint and passes the email and pass as parameters
        signup() {
          if (this.password === this.password_confirmation) {
            this.$http.plain
              .post("http://localhost:3000/signup", {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation
              })
              // If successful execute signinSuccesful
              .then(response => this.signinSuccesful(response))
              // If it doesn't run for whatever reason, execute signupFailed
              .catch(error => this.signinFailed(error));
          }
      },
```

About the CORS error, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25727411/715444

Comment: Thanks! Never had to deal with CORS before so your help was definitely appreciated.